# finding c# ways to send http requests

Tags: c#, http, automation, httprequest, httpresponse

I am trying to develop a Microsoft excel plugin to send excel sheet data to a web application. It will require the plugin to prompt username and password and then send login http request to the web application to get a session . Then it will upload data to the web application . What .net things should I use ?

Comment: Just use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx if you want a detailed answered you must provide code.  There are hundreds of examples of doing exactly what you want to do.  All you have to do is do some research on the subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Post Method Sample for send username and password. for uploading file just search "File Upload C#" in google.com or bing.com or try [C#'s WebClient.UploadFile, Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/uploadfileex.aspx)

```
// Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
// Set the Method property of the request to POST.
request.Method = "POST";
// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
string postData = "username=user&passsword=pass";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
// Get the request stream.
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
// Write the data to the request stream.
dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
// Close the Stream object.
dataStream.Close ();
// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
// Display the status.
Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
// Display the content.
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
// Clean up the streams.
reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
response.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

For HTTP communication in .NET, try [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or [System.Net.HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).